.csproj file not found while building Docker image
Hello as im trying to build Docker images for APIs i have i get the same error for each one which is for example for this service

ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open Dockerfile: no such file or directory

the command is
docker build -f Dockerfile . 

for this what the docker file looks like
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release

WORKDIR /src

COPY ["Services/Branch/Branch.API/Branch.API.csproj", "Services/Branch/Branch.API/"]

Any idea please

the Dockerfile should be present in the directory, where you try to run
docker build -f Dockerfile .
if it is in some other directory,  you need to use like
docker build -f /path/to/your/Dockerfile . 

i already tried that but the same problem it tells me that the file .csproj don't exist but in the folder its there

@medaaminee The error you posted: "ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open Dockerfile: no such file or directory" makes no such mention of a CSPROJ file, it's mentioning that the file Dockerfile cannot be found.
